# Print even/ odd-numbered lines to new column

Tags: linux, awk, sed, vim

I have a file with X number of lines in a single column and I want to print every even/odd-numbered line to a new column, is this possible in linux or `vim` editor?

For example:

Input file:

```
RESOLUTION: 1.70
UNIT: MONOMERIC
RESOLUTION: 1.80
UNIT: DIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.50
UNIT: TRIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.20
UNIT: TETRAMERIC
```

Output file, which I need:

```
RESOLUTION: 1.70    UNIT: MONOMERIC
RESOLUTION: 1.80    UNIT: DIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.50    UNIT: TRIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.20    UNIT: TETRAMERIC
```

Comment: You will have to show input and output examples. But don't expect any one to do it for you.  You are looking in the correct place (awk, or sed).

Comment: Btw [vi.se] exists and loves vim QAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data is on file z1, then

```
paste -sd "\t\n" z1
```

will produce:

```
RESOLUTION: 1.70        UNIT: MONOMERIC
RESOLUTION: 1.80        UNIT: DIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.50        UNIT: TRIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.20        UNIT: TETRAMERIC
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 3):

Try below.

```
$cat a.txt
RESOLUTION: 1.70
UNIT: MONOMERIC
RESOLUTION: 1.80
UNIT: DIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.50
UNIT: TRIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.20
UNIT: TETRAMERIC

$ cat a.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /g'
RESOLUTION: 1.70 UNIT: MONOMERIC
RESOLUTION: 1.80 UNIT: DIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.50 UNIT: TRIMERIC
RESOLUTION: 2.20 UNIT: TETRAMERIC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the correct place (awk, or sed).

`sed` is sufficient, if using gnu `sed`.

see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses

> 4.2 Selecting lines by numbers
>
> …
>
> first~step This GNU extension matches every stepth line starting with
>   line first. In particular, lines will be selected when there exists a
>   non-negative n such that the current line-number equals first + (n *
>   step). Thus, one would use 1~2 to select the odd-numbered lines and
>   0~2 for even-numbered lines; to pick every third line starting with
>   the second, ‘2~3’ would be used; to pick every fifth line starting
>   with the tenth, use ‘10~5’; and ‘50~0’ is just an obscure way of
>   saying 50.
>
> The following commands demonstrate the step address usage:
>
> $ seq 10 | sed -n '0~4p' 
>   4
>   8
>
> $ seq 10 | sed -n '1~3p' 
>   1 
>   4 
>   7
>   10

Comment: You dont provide a command which actually columnizes the input?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes the question changed, since I posted this answer (and comment requesting clarification).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trailing space on the odd-numbered lines, you could write an `ed` script:

```
{ for((line=1; line <= $(wc -l < input) / 2; line++)); do printf '%d,%dj\n' "$line" "$((line + 1))"; done; echo "wq"; } | ed -s input
```

Reformatted:

```
{ for((line=1; line <= $(wc -l < input) / 2; line++))
  do 
    printf '%d,%dj\n' "$line" "$((line + 1))"
  done
  echo "wq"
} | ed -s input
```

The general idea is to compute the number of lines, divide it by two, the print `ed` commands that will join the odd and even-numbered lines. For your eight-line sample file, the loop would produce these `ed` commands:

```
1,2j
2,3j
3,4j
4,5j
```

The final `echo` command simply tells `ed` to write the file to disk and quit (exit).

This method does not add any whitespace between the adjoined lines, so if you need to add (say) a tab, then you'd need to insert that by adding this line before the existing `printf`:

```
        printf '%ds/$/  /\n' "$line"
```

where the whitespace you see in the replacement text is a tab (enter it with <kbd>Control-V</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>).